MSAL.js "offline_access" Scope Missing from Token Response
unable to see offline_access Scope Missing from Token Response
I'm using MSAL.js in my Outlook Add-in to authenticate users and obtain tokens. My configuration includes the offline_access scope, but it appears to be missing from the token response. This prevents me from getting a refresh token. Here is my current configuration and token request code:
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
        redirectUri: _redirectUri,
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,  // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case msal.LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                }
            },
        },
    },
};

const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite", "offline_access"],
    prompt: "select_account",
};

const tokenRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite", "offline_access"],
    prompt: "select_account",
    forceRefresh: true,
};

function getTokenPopup(request, myMSALObj, username) {
    request.account = myMSALObj.getAccountByUsername(username);

    return myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request).catch((error) => {
        console.warn("Silent token acquisition fails. Acquiring token using popup");
        if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
            return myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(request)
                .then((tokenResponse) => {
                    // Log the token response to see what's included
                    console.log("Popup token acquisition successful:", tokenResponse);

                    // Check if tokenResponse includes the necessary tokens
                    const { accessToken, idToken, expiresOn, scopes, account } = tokenResponse;

                    console.log("Access Token:", accessToken);
                    console.log("ID Token:", idToken);
                    console.log("Expires On:", expiresOn);
                    console.log("Scopes:", scopes);
                    console.log("Account:", account);

                    // Check if offline_access scope is included
                    if (scopes.includes("offline_access")) {
                        console.log("Refresh token should be available.");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Refresh token is not available. Ensure offline_access scope is requested.");
                    }

                    // Return the token response for further processing
                    return tokenResponse;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Popup token acquisition failed:", error);
                });
        } else {
            console.warn("Non-interaction error occurred:", error);
        }
    });
}


I have set the permission on Azure AD as well.

Note that: MSAL do not expose the refresh tokens, the token is stored in the cache and so there is no need to sign in again.

To refresh the access token, you can make use of acquireTokenSilent function. This allows you to obtain a new access token silently using the refresh token, avoiding the need for the user to go through the sign-in process again.

As refresh tokens are stored the token cache, to get the refresh token you need to make use of getTokenCache().serialize(),  it returns the serialized token cache, which includes the refresh token for the user.
To fetch the refresh token from the cache along with access and ID token, modify the code like below:
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "ClientID",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case msal.LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                }
            },
        },
    },
};
 
const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid", "User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite", "offline_access"],
    prompt: "select_account",
};
 
const tokenRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid", "User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite", "offline_access"],
    forceRefresh: true,
};
 
const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
 
async function login() {
    try {
        const loginResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenByDeviceCode({
            scopes: loginRequest.scopes,
            deviceCodeCallback: (response) => console.log(response.message)
        });
        console.log("Login successful:", loginResponse);
        return loginResponse.account;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Login failed:", error);
    }
}
 
async function getTokenPopup(request, myMSALObj, account) {
    request.account = account;
 
    try {
        const tokenResponse = await myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request);
        console.log("Silent token acquisition successful:", tokenResponse);
        return tokenResponse;
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn("Silent token acquisition fails. Acquiring token using popup", error);
        if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
            try {
                const tokenResponse = await myMSALObj.acquireTokenByDeviceCode({
                    scopes: request.scopes,
                    deviceCodeCallback: (response) => console.log(response.message)
                });
                console.log("Popup token acquisition successful:", tokenResponse);
                return tokenResponse;
            } catch (popupError) {
                console.error("Popup token acquisition failed:", popupError);
            }
        } else {
            console.warn("Non-interaction error occurred:", error);
        }
    }
}
 
function getRefreshToken() {
    const tokenCache = msalInstance.getTokenCache().serialize();
    const parsedCache = JSON.parse(tokenCache);
    const refreshTokens = parsedCache.RefreshToken;
    const refreshTokenKey = Object.keys(refreshTokens)[0];
    const refreshToken = refreshTokens[refreshTokenKey]?.secret;
    return refreshToken;
}
 
async function acquireTokens() {
    const account = await login();
    if (account) {
        const tokenResponse = await getTokenPopup(tokenRequest, msalInstance, account);
        if (tokenResponse) {
            const refreshToken = getRefreshToken();
            const tokens = {
                accessToken: tokenResponse.accessToken,
                idToken: tokenResponse.idTokenClaims,
                refreshToken: refreshToken
            };
            console.log("Tokens:", tokens);
        }
    }
}
 
acquireTokens();

Refresh token from the cache:

Access and ID tokens:

Reference:
node.js - Handling refresh tokens in Azure (Microsoft graph) delegation flow - Stack Overflow by me
